# Passing value to form.cs from a *different* non-form

Tags: c#, .net, forms

I've read a bunch of blogs and answers about passing from a child form to parent form. That is NOT what I have, so I hope perhaps someone can help me here. Still new to this.
Using C# within .NET framework 2.0 - VS10

I have a form.cs which looks like this:

```
   if (myProxy.myID != null)
        {
            do something;
        }
        else
        {
            do something else;
        }
```

In myProxy.cs I have it initialized above like this:

```
    public static string myID = null;
```

Later in this myProxy.cs I change the value of myID, but this does not get passed to the form.cs. It seems simple, I've tried creating a subfunction just to get the ID, but that seemed to not be the way. Perhaps I did it wrong and someone can show me a better way.

I tried to see if i hard code the myID in the myProxy.cs to a specific string, that goes through, but I loose my conditional power. 
So basically I'm looking for a way to check if the myID variable is "new" or "used/changed" whatever. If it's new, it has to go do something, whereas if it is not null (not new) then it should do something else.

Thanks for any help/comments. Please bear with a newbie.

Comment: Go with events here. Check [this example](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/9355/Creating-advanced-C-custom-events).

Answer (score 1):

i think it will be good idea to use Event , i mean you could add and event to your myProxy class and then you must wire up myProxy and form classes to each other so when and changes happened in myProxy so you fire the event and then it will catch by form calss.

other way could be using threads to periodically check the myID value .

Comment: So use an event in the non-form myProxy class? I'll look it up then. Haven't seen that idea yet.

Comment: Ok well I can't get this working this way. will try a simpler way. thanks anyways. Will post if i get it